# Sql 2005 Express : Is this possible to skip After Insert trigger in loop insert scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a questionnare, having multiple sections,carrying N questions per section. Each section is paged with 10 questions. I am saving results of set of 10 questions to  table  named `Answers` using a `for loop`. Also I have a criteria to disable running section when its all questions are answered, so as to load the next section in pipleline.

On submission of 10 questions to table 'Answers' , I using a trigger to count the total numbers of questions in 'QuestionMaster' master table with the questions saved in `Answers`. If the two are equal then current section status is to false so  as to pick the next section.

My trigger is :

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[GetAnsweredQuestionCount]
On [dbo].[Answers]
After Insert
As
Begin
    Declare @sectionid as int
    Declare @companyid as int 
    Declare @Count_Inserted as int
    Declare @Count_remaining as int
Declare @userid as varchar(50)

Set @sectionid = (Select Top(1) SectionId from inserted)
Set @companyid = (Select Top(1) CompanyId from inserted)

Set @userid= (Select Top(1) UserId from inserted )

Set @Count_inserted = (Select count(id) from inserted where SectionId = @sectionid and companyid = @companyid and userid=@userid)

Set @Count_remaining = (Select count(id) from SectionQuestionMap where SectionId = @sectionid and companyid = @companyid and userid=@userid)

If @Count_inserted = @Count_remaining
    begin
        Update SectionCompanyRateMap Set IsCompleted =1 Where SectionId=@sectionid and CompanyId=@companyid
    end
End
```

My problem is that , since i am using loop to insert the records so the trigger is too firing 10 times, which I dont want. I want to know is there any way to skip the trigger for the first 9 times so that, it will be executed only once when my all questions got saved.

Comment: `(Select Top(1) SectionId from inserted)` - that's an, shall we say, *interesting* approach to dealing with the fact that `inserted` can contain multiple rows. But why not just re-write the trigger to properly cope with multi-row inserts (and then, eliminate the loop, if possible, and *perform* a multi-row insert)

Answer (score 2):

**First approach:**

You could do the insert after completing each section in one insert-query instead of looping. Therefore, trigger would only run once.

**Second approach** ( if first is not possible ):

You could define an additional bit-column holding a flag and check this in your trigger to determine whether trigger should be used or not.

**Trigger-disabling** is possible with [NOT FOR REPLICATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms152529%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option, but I doubt, this would help you. So I'd try to think of a way like the ones described in first/second approach.

Answer (score 0):

One more option and simple example

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.test10') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.test10
CREATE TABLE dbo.test10
 (
  Id int IDENTITY
  )
GO  

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_test10 ON dbo.test10
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 'Catch!' AS ColumnInTrigger
END
GO

SELECT Id AS [Start]
FROM dbo.test10

DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max),
        @i int = 1
SET @dsql = 'DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_test10 ON dbo.test10'
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql

WHILE (@i != 10)
BEGIN
  IF @i = 9
  BEGIN
    SET @dsql = 'ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.tr_test10 ON dbo.test10'
    EXEC sp_executesql @dsql        
  END

  INSERT dbo.test10
  DEFAULT VALUES

  SET @i += 1
END

SELECT Id AS [End]
FROM dbo.test10
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eba17/2)